# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) when using Pushift API to scrape Reddit Data

Tags: python, json, reddit

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
import json
import datetime
import csv

def get_pushshift_data(after, before, sub):
    url = 'https://api.pushshift.io/reddit/search/submission/?&after=' + str(after) + '&before='+ str(before) + '&subreddit='+ str(sub) + '&sort=asc&sort_type=created_utc&size=400'
    print(url)
    r = requests.get(url).json()
    # data = json.loads(r.text, strict=False)
    return r['data']

def collect_subData(subm):
    subData = list() #list to store data points
    title = subm['title']
    url = subm['url']
    try:
        flair = subm['link_flair_text']
    except KeyError:
        flair = "NaN"
    try:
        # returns the body of the posts
        body = subm['selftext']
    except KeyError:
        body = ''
    author = subm['author']
    subId = subm['id']
    score = subm['score']
    created = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(subm['created_utc']) #1520561700.0
    numComms = subm['num_comments']
    permalink = subm['permalink']

    subData.append((subId,title,body,url,author,score,created,numComms,permalink,flair))
    subStats[subId] = subData

def update_subFile():
    upload_count = 0
    location = "subreddit_data_uncleaned/"
    print("Input filename of submission file, please add .csv")
    filename = input()
    file = location + filename
    with open(file, 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        a = csv.writer(file, delimiter=',')
        headers = ["Post ID","Title","Body","Url","Author","Score","Publish Date","Total No. of Comments","Permalink","Flair"]
        a.writerow(headers)
        for sub in subStats:
            a.writerow(subStats[sub][0])
            upload_count+=1

        print(str(upload_count) + " submissions have been uploaded into a csv file")

# global dictionary to hold 'subData'
subStats = {}

# tracks no. of submissions
subCount = 0

#Subreddit to query
sub = 'politics'

# Unix timestamp of date to crawl from.
before = int(datetime.datetime(2021,5,17,0,0).timestamp())
after = int(datetime.datetime(2014,1,1,0,0).timestamp())

data = get_pushshift_data(after, before, sub)
while len(data) > 0:
    for submission in data:
        collect_subData(submission)
        subCount+=1
    
    # Calls getPushshiftData() with the created date of the last submission
    print(len(data))
    print(str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(data[-1]['created_utc'])))
    after = data[-1]['created_utc']
    data = get_pushshift_data(after, before, sub)

print(len(data))
update_subFile()
```

At line 1: I call the `get_pushshift_data(after, before, sub)` function to scrape the data and there is no error. But then when I want to the same thing again at line 11 but with **different time for** `after` variable(type: int), the program comes out the error of **JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**.

[This is the image for you to refer to which I have just described above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9qQJb.png)

[**This is the Error Image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLbko.png)

Comment: Have you done the most obvious debugging, to print out the result of `requests.get(url)` before converting the JSON?  You can't assume that every web request succeeds.  You have to check for errors.

Comment: Have you tried printing the response without parsing it to json first? If so what does the response look like? I am gonna guess that it is empty or contains an error message of some sort and that is why you are having problems

Comment: @TimRoberts, @Metareven so I have to check the result of `requests.get(url)` first, if it not empty and errors free then only can convert to JSON?

Comment: Can I modify the code in this way?
    `r = requests.get(url)`
    `# data = json.loads(r.text, strict=False)`
    `if r.status_code < 400:`
        `r.json()`
        `return r['data']`
    `else:`
        `return None`

Comment: Well, you need to save the return from the `json` function, so `r = r.json()` is closed.  You should try that and see if it's better.  And you don't necessarily need to give up; you probably want to retry it.

Comment: Ok. Ya, I did code `r = r.json()` before return. I made some typo in the previous comment.